# WCF Timeout - WSDualHttpBinding, How to set OperationTimeout

Tags: wcf, wsdualhttpbinding

I'm creating a WSDualHttpBinding (from code), setting the following timeout values:

```
 peerBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ServiceConnector_Constants.CLOSETIMEOUT);
            peerBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ServiceConnector_Constants.OPENTIMEOUT);
            peerBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ServiceConnector_Constants.SENDTIMEOUT);
```

These constant (for exasperation purposes) values are 600 seconds.

One client connects fine, the others log the following error :

"The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00"

This is at the following line of code :

```
                            _clientFactory.Open();

                        //Log(String.Format("Create Client IN 6"));
                        LogMessage("Creating client...");
                        _serviceConnection = _clientFactory.CreateChannel();
                        LogMessage("Client Created...");
```

The last logged line is "Creating Client". It appears that the CreateChannel is causing the problem.

But I've set the value > 1 minute. Whatever value I set, the Timeout is 
ALWAYS reported as 00:01:00!!

I don't understand.

I've read and read about this and the OperationTimeout property. But I cannot find anyway of setting it on a WSDualHttpBinding.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is NOT to use wsDualHTTPBinding as advised in this excellent SO solution :[why NOT to use wsDualHttpBinding in client/server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694853/wcf-timeout-wsdualhttpbinding-how-to-set-operationtimeout)

Now all is well in the world - and faster.